# Java scanner to detect blank line?

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

I've been having lots of trouble trying to get either a scanner or a buffered reader to try and detect a blank line. For example if I have a file that contains:

```
there
cat
dog
(BLANK LINE)
```

If I do this:

```
while( scan.hasNextLine() )
{
String line = scan.nextLine();
...
...
}
```

The scanner doesn't pick up the blank line. I tried to use a buffered reader also but I run into this issue. Is there some way the scanner can just return a "" whenever it finds a blank line like that? Cheers

Comment: Is the blank line the last line of input?

Comment: Yes it is the last line of input

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input has as many lines as it has `\n` characters. Given the input

```
"there\ncat\ndog\n"
```

the next-lines will be correctly divided as

```
"there\n"
"cat\n"
"dog\n"
```

(In other words, *there is no fourth blank line*, since it is not terminated by a `\n`.)

Put differently, after the `"dog\n"` has been read, the scanner (or buffered reader for that matter) has reached EOF and there's not even an empty line to return. (Note that when the lines are returned, the new-line character is stripped off.)

So, since this is the expected behavior, I don't know what the easiest fix is. I suspect that the best way to solve this is simply to append a `\n` to the input, so that the loop runs an extra iteration.

Comment: Actually, appending a newline to the end of the input sounds like it'll do the trick! The only problem is I'm very unsure how I should go about it. I'm reading in a file like this atm:    scan = new Scanner( new BufferedReader( new FileReader(args[0]) ) ); Any ideas? (I do not want to modify the file I'm reading directly and add a newline to it)

Comment: Using a `Scanner` or `BufferedReader` there's no way to tell if the line received ends with a new-line or not (which is what you need to know if you want to append a new line if it's not included in the last line of the input). You'll have to use a different approach I believe.

Comment: Edit as far as I know, scanner remove blank line - If you are certain than your file ends with a blank line, add a "\n" after the while, not elegant, but perhaps useful.